# zsh: command not found: jhipster

Tags: jhipster, yeoman-generator

I couldn't run jhipster generator, got error:
`zsh: command not found: jhipster`

My system is Ubuntu 16.04, I use zsh:

```
➜ yarn global add generator-jhipster
yarn global v0.24.5
warning No license field
[1/4] Resolving packages...
[2/4] Fetching packages...
[3/4] Linking dependencies...
[4/4] Building fresh packages...
success Installed "generator-jhipster@4.5.0" with binaries:
      - jhipster
warning No license field
Done in 1.87s.
➜ jhipster
zsh: command not found: jhipster
```

What did I missed?

Also I have this in my .zshrc:

```
# npm
export PATH="$PATH:/home/romanovi/.npm-global/bin"
export NODE_PATH="$NODE_PATH:/home/romanovi/.npm-global/lib/node_modules"

# Yarn
export PATH="$PATH:`yarn global bin`"
```

Answer (score 6):

I had the same problem and solved it by running `yarn global bin` and adding the returned value to my PATH.

Answer (score 4):

There seems to be an issue with the last update of jhipster to jhipster cli.
Can you try `yo jhipster` instead while #JHipster try to fix the jhipster cli.

Answer (score 2):

This issue seems to be fixed. Reinstall generator-jhipster and it is working again.

```
yarn global add generator-jhipster
```

Answer (score 1):

We had an issue yesterday with JHipster v4.5.0, it should be solved today with v4.5.1. Can you try it out?

Don't hesitate to give feedback on https://github.com/jhipster/generator-jhipster/issues/5797

Answer (score 1):

**Update Dec 2018**

Just updating the path didn't work for me. I had to also set the yarn prefix.

- Ubuntu 18.04.1 LTS (bionic)
- yarn 1.12.3
- npm v3.5.2
- node v8.10.0
- zsh

**Steps**

1. Confirm your global bin path

   ```
   yarn global bin
   ```

I got: `/home/username/.yarn/bin`

2. **set yarn prefix:**

   make sure your yarn prefix is the parent directory of your bin directory. You can confirm by running

   ```
   yarn config get prefix
   ```

   when I ran this, my prefix was empty, so I set it:

   ```
   yarn config set prefix ~/.yarn
   ```
3. **add the following to ~/.bash_profile**

   ```
   export PATH="$PATH:`yarn global bin`"
   ```

   > **for zsh users, be sure to add this line to ~/.zshrc**
4. **restart your shell or start a new one**

   `bash -l`  or `zsh`

Answer (score -1):

**Update September 2019**

Just saw this problem on Mac OSX. I gave up on yarn for this.

Instead, I ran `npm install -g generator-jhipster` instead, and everything installed as expected.

```
❯ jhipster --version                                   

INFO! Using JHipster version installed globally
6.2.0
```

Answer (score -2):

Try with `sudo`.

`sudo yarn global add generator-jhipster`

Comment: Can someone explain me why this is wrong? It was worked for me. and with the experience of npm, we used to use 'sudo' to installing global packages. thats why I use same with yarn.

Comment: it is less save to do it with sudo.